# use python list comprehension to update dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries and would like to update the value for key 'price' with 0 if key price value is equal to ''

```
data=[a['price']=0 for a in data if a['price']=='']
```

Is it possible to do something like that? I have tried also with

```
a.update({'price':0})
```

but did not work as well...

Comment: You can't use `data=[a['price']=0 for a in data if a['price']=='']`, this is for identifying a list, not changing it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Assignments are statements, and statements are not usable inside list comprehensions. Just use a normal for-loop:

```
data = ...
for a in data:
    if a['price'] == '':
        a['price'] = 0
```

And for the sake of completeness, you can also use this abomination (but that doesn't mean you should):

```
data = ...

[a.__setitem__('price', 0 if a['price'] == '' else a['price']) for a in data]
```

Comment: No, you **really** should not use a list comprehension. You are building a list of `None` references, then discarding that list again right after. That's a waste of cycles and memory. List comprehensions should only be used *when creating a list object*, not as a replacement for `for` loops in general.

Comment: Feel free to edit out that part of the answer but I really don't think that I implied this to be a good idea. It can be done if you need to have it.

Answer (score 11):

if you're using dict.update don't assign it to the original variable since it returns None

```
[a.update(price=0) for a in data if a['price']=='']
```

without assignment will update the list...

Answer (score 1):

It is bad practice, but possible:

```
import operator

l = [
    {'price': '', 'name': 'Banana'},
    {'price': 0.59, 'name': 'Apple'},
    {'name': 'Cookie', 'status': 'unavailable'}
]

[operator.setitem(p, "price", 0) for p in l if "price" in p and not p["price"]]
```

The cases in which there's no key "price" is handled and price is set to `0` if `p["price"]` is `False`, an empty string or any other value that python considers as `False`.

Note that the list comprehension returns garbage like `[None]`.

Comment: You already note this, but you **really** should not use a list comprehension. You are building a list of `None` references, then discarding that list again right after. That's a waste of cycles and memory. List comprehensions should only be used *when creating a list object*, not as a replacement for `for` loops in general.

Comment: That's interesting. I always felt "obliged" to use list comprehensions instead of for..loops because I thought they were more efficient. I guess I've confused that with generators.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

You can't use `update` directly to dict because `update` is returns nothing and dict is only temporary variable in this case (inside list comprehension), so it will be no affect, **but**, you can apply it to iterable itself because iterable is persistance variable in this case.

instead of using

```
[my_dict['k'] = 'v' for my_dict in iterable]  # As I know, assignment not allowed in list comprehension
```

use

```
[iterable[i].update({'k': 'v'}) for i in range(len(iterable))]  # You can use enumerate also
```

So list comprehension itself will be return useless data, but your dicts will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary comprehensions

```py
data = [
    {'price': '', 'id': 0},
    {'price': 7, 'id': 1},
    {'price': 26, 'id': 2},
]
data = [{k: 0 for k in d if k == 'price'} if d['price'] == '' else d for d in data]
print(data)
```

```py
[
    {'price': 0, 'id': 0},
    {'price': 7, 'id': 1},
    {'price': 26, 'id': 2},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `update` which returns `None`, merge the dictionary with another storing the default value for the price key.

```
>>> data = [{"price": 1}, {"price": ""}]
>>> default_price = {"price": 0}
>>> [d if d["price"] else {**d, **default_price} for d in data]
[{'price': 1}, {'price': 0}]
```

That will work in Python 3.5 or greater. From Python 3.9 you can also use the union operator.

```
>>> [d if d["price"] else d | default_price for d in data]
[{'price': 1}, {'price': 0}]
```